# Creating Listbox dynamically in Grid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have been searching many blogs to find. how to create Listbox dynamically in grid cell. And i want to add listbox items Horizontally in that Grid column. For example, i want to show the week days in that column means, i have the code in XAML to do this.

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"   Margin="0,0,10,0">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBoxItem> Mon </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem> Tue </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem> Wed </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem> Thu </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem> Fri </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

but i dont know how to create the same in Dynamically. I have one button for this, if i click the button it should create Listbox with items in a column. And again if click the button it should create another Listbox in next row of that grid.

this is my code behind.

```
 public int i=0;
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        RowDefinition row0 = new RowDefinition();
        row0.Height = new GridLength(40);
        grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(row0);

        ColumnDefinition col0 = new ColumnDefinition();           
        col0.Width = new GridLength(150);   
        grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col0);

        Listbox lb=new Listbox();
        ?
        ?
        Grid.SetRow(?, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(?, 0);

        i++;

    }
```

Comment: [This blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) has a good example using an ItemsControl. You can apply to same technique to a ListBox as well.

Comment: i want sample code for dynamic creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var panelTemplate = new ItemsPanelTemplate();
var stackPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
stackPanel.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
panelTemplate.VisualTree = stackPanel;

ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
listBox.ItemsPanel = panelTemplate;
listBox.Items.Add("Mon");
listBox.Items.Add("Tue");
listBox.Items.Add("Wed");
listBox.Items.Add("Thu");
listBox.Items.Add("Fri");

this.grid.Children.Add(listBox);
listBox.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
listBox.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
```

Comment: its looking good..! but i dont find any Multiple selection mode here.! i want to use SelectionMode as Multiple.

Comment: listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;